# Power function introduction into calculator

Tags: java, javascript, android, calculator

I have this Java code but I do not know how to introduce power, sin, cos or other functions in it. I looked for it various websites but no luck finding it

```
public class calculator extends Activity {

 private WebView mWebView;
 private StringBuilder mMathString;
 private ButtonClickListener mClickListener;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

  // Create the math string
  mMathString = new StringBuilder();

  // Enable javascript for the view
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  // Set the listener for all the buttons
  mClickListener = new ButtonClickListener();
  int idList[] = { R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2,
    R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6,
    R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.buttonLeftParen,
    R.id.buttonRightParen, R.id.buttonPlus, R.id.buttonPlus,
    R.id.buttonMinus, R.id.buttonDivide, R.id.buttonTimes,
    R.id.buttonDecimal, R.id.buttonBackspace, R.id.buttonClear, R.id.buttonPow };

  for(int id : idList) {
   View v = findViewById(id);
   v.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
  }

 }

 private void updateWebView() {

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

  builder.append("<html><body>");
  builder.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write('");
  builder.append(mMathString.toString());
  builder.append("');");
  builder.append("document.write('<br />=' + eval(\"");
  builder.append(mMathString.toString());
  builder.append("\"));</script>");
  builder.append("</body></html>");

  mWebView.loadData(builder.toString(), "application/xhtml", "UTF-8");
 }

 private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.buttonBackspace:
    if(mMathString.length() > 0)
     mMathString.deleteCharAt(mMathString.length()-1);
    break;
   case R.id.buttonClear:
    if(mMathString.length() > 0)
     mMathString.delete(0, mMathString.length());
    break;
   default:
    mMathString.append(((Button) v).getText());
   }

   updateWebView();
  }

 }

}
```

could someone say how to introduce power function?

Comment: There is javascript involved in his `updateWebView` method.

Comment: "How does this program work?" is not a good Stack Overflow question.  You should focus on **specific** parts of it that you don't understand.

Comment: I think this part of my question was edited. I wanted to know how I can introduce power, sin, cos and other functions. If someone could help with one, I could probably work out others

Comment: Jon, his question is in reference to java AND javascript code. I am adding the tags for both to his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question I think you're really wanting to know, which is how does THAT code calculate math functions without using Java's math package...

That code you are looking at prints a bunch of javascript to an HTML page, including `eval("your math expression")` with the entered mathmatical expression within the eval, and that eval line is what is actually doing the mathmatical evaluation, and it is doing so using javascript, not Java to actually do the math.

http://javascriptsource.com/math-related/5-function.html has example of doing powers using javascript's eval function...you would have to modify the javascript generated by the app in order to evaluate powers in that way.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Hopefully I will be able to do it. Thanks

Comment: Could you please just how I need to modify javascript? As I can't find javascript that I could add functions I need

Comment: Could you just say what is an operator for power function in javascript? I found loads of others but not this one...

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look at Java's [Math package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html). It has lots of math functions including the ones you are looking for. You may need to add an import of `import java.lang.Math;` at the beginning of the file you use the Math functions in, if the import is not already there.

For example, `double answer = Math.pow(firstnum,secondnum);` is the function to raise one number to the power of another, or `double answer = Math.sin(anum)` to give the sin of a value in the variable anum, and so on.

As you read through the javadoc for that class you will see additional functions that should supply the rest of the "scientific" calculator features you want.

Keep in mind also that integers and doubles do have limits to their storage capacities, so you may want to consider how to handle overflow if someone decides to do something crazy like 100,000^100,000,000. If having enough precision for really really large numbers is important to you, you may also want to look into classes such as [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use java [Math](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=math%20java&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html&ei=z9bsTvfCE8ej4gThyPzgCA&usg=AFQjCNE1Mq6qab7f9sswDdwQlWPNdSQyMQ&sig2=ro4N3HwTcrUgy_e19_G9yQ) API. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/beyondmath.html).

Answer (score 0):

Java has these functions built-in in the `java.lang.Math` class as static methods.
You can cal them just like this:

**Power**, using `Math.pow(double, double)`

```
double number = 3.42d;
double exponent = 5.14d;
double power = Math.pow(number, exponent);
```

**Square Root**, using `Math.sqrt(double)`

```
double shortSide1 = 4.0d;
double shortSide2 = 3.0d;
double longSide = Math.sqrt(shortSide1 * shortSide1 + shortSide2 * shortSide2);
// All credits goto Pythagoras.
```

**Sin, cos, tan**

```
double angle = 2.13d;
double sin = Math.sin(angle);
double cos = Math.cos(angle);
double tan = Math.tan(angle);
```

**Arcsin, arccos, arctan**

```
double value = 0.13d;
double asin = Math.asin(value);
double acos = Math.acos(value);
double atan = Math.atan(value);
```

All these functions are Native (not written in Java), which mean that they will perform as good as possible on your platform.

Comment: I just got lost. I found this code in http://www.androiddom.com/2011/04/creating-android-calculator-tutorial.html  . It actually works, but I can't find where it makes all calculations what I could add these functions

Comment: The calculator you linked is much more complex. It evaluates an expression and solves it. I would first try to create a simple calculator which executes one operation at once. Eg: `5*3`, `sin(2)`.

Comment: could ou just say in which part it actually does calculations? When I could try to understand it and change or add something

Comment: Take a look at the method `updateWebView()`. You will see the author made use of JavaScript to evaluate the composed expression by calling the `eval()` method of JavaScript. This is completely worthless when you are trying to learn some Java. Again: try to make a simple calculator which does one operation of two number and an operator.

Comment: I think that I just need to give a right value for buttonPow. Which would anable a right function in eval(). Could this be a case? ( now buttonPow represents ^)

Comment: Could you say what is power operator in javascript, I sincerely can't find it